# Confusion about principle value of arg(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

I got badly confused about principle value concept when I was looking proof of why $z^{1/2}$ is discontinuous on negative real axis. I understand the proof (all proofs I checked , use  the fact that if we approach -1 in  ccw around unit circle limit is $i$ and if we approach -1 in cw sense ,limit is $-i$. Ok ,I understood this but I started feeling this discontinuity which have arise is only because of how we have defined our principal value of arg z which (-π,π] .What if we set initially that principle value should be taken as [0,2π]. Now if I approach same -1 in ccw and cw sense around unit circle , is it not true that limit will be $i$ in both ways??I am beginner in this course .Please help.Thank you.

Comment: Oh..will it be discontinuous on positive real axis then.

Comment: Yes you are correct,  the jump is now on the positive real axis.